Process of automated replacement of existing windows installation with debian
i have a bunch of PCs with windows installed (same Partitions and disk size) and want to switch to debian.
The problem is that all of the PC are not at the same place and can only be accessed via Remote Desktop. There are also any remote hands available.
Is there a process or could someone suggest a process on how to achieve this fully remotely and automated?
What i though of was:

Log onto windows with remote desktop
execute a power shell script that will:

create a new partition
download and extract the debian net installer on it
set the newly created partition to auto boot on next restart (how to do that on windows?)
restart


debian net installer should remove the windows partition, create a new one and install debian on that and setup grub to boot from the newly installed debian.

Do anyone has experience with something like this and would this work?
Or do you have suggestions for a different approach?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
